# Clone a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Before explaining my bash problem let me give you some context:

I am writing some scripts using a bash "framework" we use at my current job. One of the feature of the framework is to init a sets of environments variables useful to run jobs on our cluster infrastructure.

These variables depend on a date specified by `$YY`, `$mm` and `$dd` which are also environment variables (yes, this is wired). To use the framework you start by defining the date and then you call a function to init other vars. This works fine when you write scripts that need variables for a specific day only. Today I am writing something which needs variables for 2 different days. Writing this I face a strange issue. For you to better understand the problem I wrote this code that simulate it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function assign(){
    date=$1
    date[1]=$YY
    date[2]=$mm
    date[3]=$dd
}

function display() {
    date=$1
    echo "${date[1]}/${date[2]}/${date[3]}"
}

export YY=2012
export mm=09
export dd=20
declare -a my_date1=()
assign $my_date1

export YY=2012
export mm=08
export dd=20
declare -a my_date2=()
assign $my_date2

display $my_date1
display $my_date2
```

The expected output is:

```
2012/09/20
2012/08/20
```

But the output is:

```
2012/08/20
2012/08/20
```

At first I thought that the assign function filled the array with reference to `$YY`, `$mm` and `$dd` instead of their values. But then I try with the following code and it doesn't change the result.

```
date[1]=$(echo $YY)
date[2]=$(echo $mm)
date[3]=$(echo $dd)
```

Can somebody explain me what append?
Maybe something wired with `date=$1`...

Comment: Try changing the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash -xv` to see how bash interprets the code.

Comment: There is never a need to export a variable twice, and there is no apparent need in this script to export them even once.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: it's why I put some context to my question! I did these things because of the crazy framework we use at my current job. I asked this question to understand this behavior not to solve the problem I faced at work. Even if this script is stupid I learned something from understanding it. Thanks to chepner for his answer and choroba for his suggestion, it enable me to fully understand the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are not passed by either value or reference in bash. Rather, the value of the expansion of the array is passed by value. When you write

```
assign $my_date1
```

the `date` variable inside `assign` is null, since `$my_date1` expands to an empty string and disappears after word-splitting before the function is called. As a result, `$1` is unset.

But `date`, being a global variable because it was not declared as local, is set correctly using `YY` et al, then *reset* on the second call to `assign`.

Also, note that the first line of your functions does not make `date` a reference to the argument; it's really just setting the 0th element of what becomes the global `date` array to the expansion of `$1`.

---

Having said I'll that, I'll show you a way to fake it using the `declare` built-in and indirect parameter expansion.

```
function assign () {
    ref=$1
    # Without the -g, we'd declare function-local parameters. The argument is a
    # string to evaluate as a variable assignment. If $ref=my_date1, then we do
    # 'my_date1[1]=$YY', 'my_date1[2]=$mm', etc.
    declare -g "$ref[1]=$YY"
    declare -g "$ref[2]=$mm"
    declare -g "$ref[3]=$dd"
}

function display () {
    ref=$1
    # If $ref=my_date1, then idx
    # iterates over my_date[1], my_date[2], my_date[3].
    # E.g. ${!idx} in the first iteration is ${my_date[1]}.
    arr=()
    for idx in $ref[{1,2,3}]; do
        arr+=( ${!idx} )
    done
    local IFS="/"
    echo "${arr[*]}"
}

export YY=2012 mm=09 dd=20
assign my_date1    # The *name* of the array; no need to predeclare

export YY=2012 mm=08 dd=20
assign my_date2    # The *name* of the array; no need to predeclare

# Again, just the *names* of the arrays
display my_date1
display my_date2
```